# How can I emulate a factitious ajax search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

All I want to do is this: reducing the opacity of an element and increasing it again after a short time. So I don't want to send any ajax request. Just I want to make a delay.

Something like this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){

  $('.search_result').animate({
        opacity: 0.3,
      }, 50);
          
   /* I need a delay here */
          
   $('.search_result').animate({
        opacity: 1,
      }, 50);         
})
```

```css
p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<button>seach</button>
<div class="search_result">
  <p>post1</p>
  <p>post2</p>
  <p>post3</p>
  <p>post4</p>
</div>
```

As you see that process happens so fast. How can I implement a delay on the way of it? In other word how can I make it slow?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`delay(1000)`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) in jquery to chain the methods.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {

  $('.search_result').animate({
      opacity: 0.3,
    }, 50).delay(1000)
    .animate({
      opacity: 1,
    }, 50);
})
```

```css
p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<button>seach</button>
<div class="search_result">
  <p>post1</p>
  <p>post2</p>
  <p>post3</p>
  <p>post4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @stack if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.